# How to create table column on the basis of database entries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created `Financial` scaffold that has `one_to_many` association with `Year`. I want each financial entries has many years budget associated with it. Now I want to render years data in respectively financial index column how can I dynamically generate column?

`Financial` index.html.erb

```rb
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="15">head ID</th>
        <th colspan="3" width="60" class="text-center">Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @financials.each do |financial| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= financial.cost_head_id %></td>
          <%= "HERE I Want to generate column based on it's year entries in column" %>
         </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

`Year` form.html.erb

```rb
<div class="row">
  <div class=" columns large-3 field">
    <%= form.label :year %>
    <%= form.date_select :year, { :discard_day => true, :discard_month => true, :discard_year => false, :include_blank => true } %>
  </div>

  <div class="field columns large-3">
    <%= form.label :budget %>
    <%= form.text_field :budget %>
  </div>
  <div class="field columns large-3"></div>
</div>
  <div class="actions text-center">
    <%= form.submit :class=>"button primary"%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

model financial.rb

```rb
  has_many :years
```

Comment: Do you want to show form on each column or just data?

Comment: @praveenkumar hey come to this updated question- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60387333/how-can-i-render-form-data-to-other-view-in-rails?noredirect=1#comment106825095_60387333]

Comment: @praveenkumar i have also added screenshot of problem there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**index.html.erb**

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th width="15">head ID</th>
    <th colspan="3" width="60" class="text-center">Action</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <% @financials.each do |financial| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= financial.cost_head_id %></td>
      <% financial.years.each do |year| %>
        <%= render partial: 'years/form', locals: {year: year} %>
      <% end %>
     </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Your `year.html.erb` should be partial, which are named as `_year.html.erb`. Read more [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)

Comment: error- ```ActionView::MissingTemplate in Financials#index ```

Comment: is there any way to pass instance variable from controller to resolve this problem as i mentioned in my question.

Comment: Did you change your Year `form.html.erb` to a partial? Also, tell me what is the directory structure you have inside your views?

Comment: Since this is an `index` action for `financial` and not years, there is no point providng an instance variable for the year in the index.

Comment: hey i have created year scaffold with ``` year:datetime budget:float``` so ```form.html.erb``` is already a partial ```_form.html.erb```

Comment: Your partial call should be `years/form`, I edited the answer, check once.